# How to activate the use of a GPU on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gpu

I am using AWS to make some predictions using a NLP model I have trained.
I activated a compute environment using:

- min vCPU = 0
- max vCPU = 5
- instance type = g4dn.xlarge

I am now running my code with number of gpu cofnigured as 1, but it feels like the GPU is not 'activated'.
This is the script that I am running to check the GPU status:

```
#Verifica se CUDA è disponibile
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    # Ottieni il numero di GPU disponibili
    num_gpus = torch.cuda.device_count()
    logging.info(f"Numero di GPU disponibili: {num_gpus}")

    #Stampa informazioni su ciascuna GPU
    for i in range(num_gpus):
        gpu_name = torch.cuda.get_device_name(i)
        logging.info(f"GPU {i}: {gpu_name}")
else:
    logging.info("Nessuna GPU disponibile, solo CPU.")
```

and it returns "Nessuna GPU disponibile, solo CPU.".

Any tips on how to activate the GPU (or check if the GPU is activated)?